# HTML: Automatic generated date and time

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat

I'm trying to implement a time stamp on a tomcat server page. It should always show the current time and date whenever I trigger a button.

Right now I'm using this:

```
<iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i4gxfr9k/n237/tlcn/fn2/ftb/tt0/tw0/tm3/ts1/tb4" frameborder="0" width="74" height="36"></iframe>
```

It is a auto-generated time and date view I just found in the web. It is working fine, except the problem that it is always visible and not only when clicking on the button.

HTML-File:

Dev. Tool

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <p:panelGrid styleClass="main-panel" columns="2">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="WorkON Dev. Quality Check Tool" style="font-size:16px" />
            <h:outputLink value="https://inside-wiki.bosch.com/confluence/display/woco/18.0+Dev.+tool+according+to+Dev.+guideline"
                target="_blank">

                <h:graphicImage id="helpIcon" value="/imgs/help.png" style="margin-left:10px" />
                <p:tooltip for="helpIcon" value="Go to wiki for more information" />
            </h:outputLink>
            <p:commandButton value="Validate apl" id="valiNoApl" actionListener="#{fileManager.checkAplExistToExcel()}" ajax="false"
                style="width: 158px; height: 40px" rendered="false" />
            <p:commandButton value="Trigger Batch Validation!" id="trigerBatch" actionListener="#{fileManager.writeResultToExcel()}" ajax="false"
                style="width: 158px; height: 40px; position: relative; left: 300px;" />
            <p:tooltip for="trigerBatch" value="Validate all projects under '/WOQC' folder to excel report.  It will take some minutes!" />

        </f:facet>

        <p:panel style="width:500px;border:0; padding:0;">
            <p:panel style="border:0; padding:0;">              
                <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{validator.validateAll}" mode="advanced" update="projectDetails,valiResult" sizeLimit="1000000"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|txt|zip)$/" multiple="true" />
                    <p id="demo"></p>

                    <script> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date(); </script>
            </p:panel>

            <p:panel style="margin-top:30px;border:0">

            <h:outputText value="                           " />
                <h:outputText value="Validation result :" style="font-weight: bold" />

            </p:panel>

            <p:dataTable id="valiResult" var="_item" value="#{validator.validationItems}">

                <p:column headerText="Code" width="10%" style="text-align:center" styleClass="pass-item-green" rendered="#{_item.result.flag == 'Pass'}">
                    <h:outputText id="valiCodePass" value="#{_item.code}" />
                    <p:tooltip for="valiCodePass" value="#{_item.content}" showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Result" width="90%" resizable="false" styleClass="pass-item-green" rendered="#{_item.result.flag == 'Pass'}"
                    style="white-space: normal; text-align:center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{_item.result.flag} : #{_item.result.content}" rendered="#{_item.result.content != null}" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{_item.result.flag}" rendered="#{_item.result.content == null}" />

                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Code" width="10%" style="text-align:center" styleClass="fail-item-red" rendered="#{_item.result.flag == 'Fail'}">
                    <h:outputText id="valiCodeFail" value="#{_item.code}" />
                    <p:tooltip for="valiCodeFail" value="#{_item.content}" showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Result" width="90%" resizable="false" styleClass="fail-item-red" rendered="#{_item.result.flag == 'Fail'}"
                    style="white-space: normal; text-align:center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{_item.result.flag} : #{_item.result.content}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Code" width="10%" style="text-align:center" styleClass="warn-item-yellow" rendered="#{_item.result.flag == 'Warn'}">
                    <h:outputText id="valiCodeWarn" value="#{_item.code}" />
                    <p:tooltip for="valiCodeWarn" value="#{_item.content}" showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Result" width="90%" resizable="false" styleClass="warn-item-yellow" rendered="#{_item.result.flag == 'Warn'}"
                    style="white-space: normal; text-align:center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{_item.result.flag} : #{_item.result.content}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>



        <p:panel id="projectDetails" style="width:500px;border:0px;padding-top: 5px;">
            <h:outputText value="Project details :" style="font-weight: bold;" />

            <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:20px;border:0" columnClasses="project-info-col-label,project-info-col-value">    

                <h:outputText value="Project name (in source)" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.name}" />

                <h:outputText value="Project key" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.key}" />

                <h:outputText value="Language available" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.lanInfo}" />

                <h:outputText value="Interface | configed -> used" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.itfInfo}" />

                <h:outputText value="Interface | web service | used" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.itConfig.wfIterfaces.size()}" />

                <h:outputText value="Interface | old excel | used" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.itConfig.excelIterfaces.size()}" />

                <h:outputText value="Interface | database | used" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.itConfig.dbIterfaces.size()}" />

                <h:outputText value="Workflow | configured | used" />
                <h:outputText value="" rendered="#{validator.project.configuredWfs.size() == null}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.configuredWfs.size()} -> #{validator.project.usedWfs.size()}"
                    rendered="#{validator.project.configuredWfs.size() != null}" />

                <h:outputText value="Escalation | used" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.escalationConfig.escalationItems.size()}" />

                <h:outputText value="Unused custom field amount" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.unusedCustomField}" />

                <h:outputText value="Lines of javascript" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.getJavaLines()}" />

                <h:outputText value="Lines of velocityscript" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.getVelocityLines()}" />

                <h:outputText value="Amount of used user picker" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.getUserPicker()}" />

                <h:outputText value="IssueType | configed -> used" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.getIssueTypeInfo()}" />

                <h:outputText value="IssueType list" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.getIssueType()}" />

                <h:outputText value="Used Non-standard status" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.getStatus()}" />

                <h:outputText value="Used Non-standard resolution" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.getLangPropertiesNames()}" />

                <h:outputText value="Amount of used parallel approval lines // Amount of used sequential approval lines" />
                <h:outputText value="#{validator.project.getParallelApprovalLines()} // #{validator.project.getSequentialApprovalLines()}" 
                rendered="#{validator.project.getParallelApprovalLines() != null}" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>



        <f:facet name="footer">
            <center>
                <h:outputText value="Innovated and developed by CI/AFR-CN  V1.4" style="color:grey" />
            </center>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panelGrid>


</h:form>

<p:ajaxStatus style="width:64px;height:64px;position:fixed;right:5px;bottom:5px">
    <f:facet name="start">
        <p:graphicImage value="/imgs/loading.gif" />
    </f:facet>

    <f:facet name="complete">
        <h:outputText value="" />
    </f:facet>
</p:ajaxStatus>
```

If you know how to show the date/time when clicking a button, please respond.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you open to use some JS?

Comment: already write some code down, i could help you implement that for example look at this im working right now i get the current date and displaying on my mother language (spanish) and playing with dates http://majestic-wave-16-154974.sae1.nitrousbox.com/ i can help you if you want, make some github repo PD: the code below it very basic and i know it look boring its just an example :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to use JS code try this

You can use an script tag like this

```
<script>
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
</script>
```

and html tag like this 
**calling js code**

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

and it will get you the current date, also if you want to improve better performance and languages on you web page i suggest you to use

[moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Try to use some JS code to show dates, etc i would be a nice behavior on whatever you are doing

Comment: I already found this JS on "http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp".
But it is as the frame above always visible.

Comment: ok so baa my bad i don't get you point i will edit my answer wait

Comment: This is an alternative way to create the date itself. Personally, I think this is a little better than using an iFrame, however you must combine this with my answer regarding adding a button & jquery to make it show/hide. The problem of showing/hiding is not caused by the fact that this is an iFrame.

Comment: @Etjana That methode works fine for me, could you please also tell me how to hide the date and time? I only want to display it when this code is used.
`<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{validator.validateAll}" mode="advanced" update="projectDetails,valiResult" sizeLimit="1000000"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|txt|zip)$/" multiple="true" />`

Right now, the date appears when I load/reload the page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be helpful if you could please provide a little more info (perhaps the full .html for the page?), however here's my best guess:

An iFrame is basically a window into another page - in your case, the free.timeanddate page. However, to make this iFrame hide or show, you'd need javascript or jquery in order to change the iFrame's visibility. Here's a link to a JSFiddle to help you out: http://jsfiddle.net/KingOfTheNerds/dd8cy97p/

An example of the jquery is:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

Comment: Hey, I'm a beginner in HTML and JS. Can in write both, the script and the html code into my .html?

    `<script>
    $( "p:commandButton" ).click(function() {
      $( "iframe" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
    });
    </script>
    

<iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i4gxfr9k/n237/tlcn/fn2/ftb/tt0/tw0/tm3/ts1/tb4" frameborder="0" width="74" height="36"></iframe>`

Comment: @Julian - this is almost correct. You need to also add a button to your html. Here's another jfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/KingOfTheNerds/adaq974z/

You also need to add jQuery to the page in the html head. You can get the code for this from Google's CDN: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: @Julian - did this work for you? If so, can you please mark the question as answered by clicking the check mark next to the answer you want to accept. Thanks!

Comment: I have already implemented a button. When I add your jQuery to my code the button is not visible anymore. But I want the button to be always visible and only the time hidden. I will post you my current HTML code.

Comment: `<h:head>
 <title>Tool</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{request.contextPath}/imgs/favicon.ico" />
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</h:head>`

Comment: `<h:body>
     <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{validator.validateAll}" mode="advanced" update="projectDetails,valiResult" sizeLimit="1000000"
      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|txt|zip)$/" multiple="true" />
    <script> $( "fileUpload" ).click(function() { $( "iframe" ).slideToggle( "slow" ); }); </script> 
    <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i4gxfr9k/n237/tlcn/fn2/ftb/tt0/tw0/tm3/ts‌​1/tb4" frameborder="0" width="74" height="36"></iframe>
</h:body>`

Comment: @Julian - I don't have a way of testing the fileUpload class from a Tomcat/JSF application, however I found this StackOverflow article that suggests you should assign an id to that tag, and then reference the ID from your jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439699/primefaces-file-upload-drop-file-outside-of-pfileupload-anywhere-in-the-page 

Also - the code in your original post does not contain the iFrame at all. Perhaps you can update your original post to contain some code that follows the MCVE guidelines found here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

I hope this helps!