# JSF fileupload by dragging file anywhere into the page

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I'm currently using the drag&drop feature of Primefaces fileUpload component. It works fine, but what I want is to upload files directly by dragging them anywhere into my page, without the need of clicking a button.

I tried this:

```
$('.dropzone').on({
    'dragover dragenter': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
    'drop': function (e) {
        var dataTransfer = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        if (dataTransfer && dataTransfer.files.length) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $.each(dataTransfer.files, function (i, file) {

              uploadFile([{"name": "filename", "value": file.name}]);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```
<p:remoteCommand name="uploadFile" action="#{bean.uploadFile()}" />
```

```
public void uploadFile(){
   String filename = 
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
       .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("filename");
}
```

The problem is that this works for the filename, but not for the file itself. Is this the right approach anyway or is there a way to forward the `files` list to Primefaces fileUpload and submit the files programmatically without using the gui-component?

Comment: have you tried this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439699/primefaces-file-upload-drop-file-outside-of-pfileupload-anywhere-in-the-page) before?

Comment: Yes, but it did not work. I'm not sure if this solution still works for Primefaces 6.0.

Comment: Im not sure if it satisfy your need but there is this thing: [Dropzone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018632/use-dropzone-with-jsf)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38018632 should indeed fully answer your question. Is this true? It was mentioned in above comment of sunofkyuss, but you didn't post any feedback on it.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test it yet, but the answer looks pretty promising.

Answer (score 0):

It is already there in the showcase.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/auto.xhtml

Need `auto="true"` to get this done.

**Update:**

Execute following javascript just after rendering the file upload div. 
Then you can drop allowed file types to anywhere in the page.

```
$('.ui-fileupload').fileupload({
      dropZone: $(document)
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer *"What I want is to upload files directly by dragging them anywhere into my page"*

Comment: Uh, the question states that. Try reading the question (and all comments and other answers) before posting an answer/comment.

Comment: `InputStream in = FileUploadEvent.getInputStream();` will have a pointer to the file

Comment: OP already knows this all. OP just want to be able to upload a file by dragging it **anywhere** into the page instead of only into `<p:fileUpload>` box. In question's comments you can find a link to another Q&A which has this already answered.

Comment: Updated the answer. Now can drop them **anywhere** into the page and tested it. If this doesn't work, sorry that is all I can do.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try `dragDropSupport="true"`?

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true"
                      update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
```

It works very well for me.

Comment: This doesn't answer *"What I want is to upload files directly by dragging them anywhere into my page"*